# JS in page head section isn't excecuting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that handles a semi-complex contact form. The site is built using a website building platform called Duda and I think there may be timing issues as they load a bunch of scripts of their own. Anyway I'm getting a ReferenceError: price is not defined, error.

Price gets called onChange on inputs, for example:

```
<input value="Yes" name="dmform-9" type="radio" id="watch-me-hide" checked="checked" onchange="price()"/>
```

The script works sometimes, then other times not. Very frustrating. Does anyone know how to make sure that my functions get loaded in this situation?

Here is the whole script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type="radio"]").click(function() {
        alert("here");
        var ids = ["#occupiedBy", "#nameOccupied", "#phoneOccupied", "#mobileOccupied", "#emailOccupied"];

    if($(this).attr("id") == "watch-me-hide" || $(this).attr("id") == "watch-me-show") {

        if ($(this).attr("id") == "watch-me-hide") {

          $("#show-me").hide();

          ids.forEach((id) => $(id).prop("required", false));            

        }

        else if ($(this).attr("id") == "watch-me-show"){

            $("#show-me").show();

            ids.forEach((id) => $(id).prop("required", true)); 
        }
        else {

        }

    } else if($(this).attr("id") == "hideShowInDepth-hide" || $(this).attr("id") == "hideShowInDepth-show") {


            if ($(this).attr("id") == "hideShowInDepth-hide") {
                $("#moreRooms").hide();
                price(null);
                ids.forEach((id) => $(id).prop("required", false));                  
            }
            else if ($(this).attr("id") == "hideShowInDepth-show"){
                $("#moreRooms").show();
                price(null);
                ids.forEach((id) => $(id).prop("required", true));     

            }
        }

        else{

        }
   });

};   


function price() {

    var priceIncrement = 70;
    var minimumPrice = "189.00";
    var basic = document.getElementById("hideShowInDepth-hide");
    var advanced = document.getElementById("hideShowInDepth-show");
    var ids = ["numberAdditionalRooms", "numberLaundries", "bedrooms", "numberLounges", "numberDining", "numberKitchens", "numberBathrooms", "numberHallways", "numberGarages"];

    if ((basic.checked == true) && (advanced.checked == false)) {

        /* Get number of rooms for basic inspection */

        var e = document.getElementById("bedrooms");
        var numberOfBedrooms = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

        if (numberOfBedrooms == 0){
           document.getElementById("totalPrice").textContent = "0.00";

        }

        else if ((numberOfBedrooms <= 3) && (numberOfBedrooms >= 1)){
           document.getElementById("totalPrice").textContent = minimumPrice;

        }

        else if ((numberOfBedrooms <= 6) && (numberOfBedrooms >= 3)){
           document.getElementById("totalPrice").textContent = "259.00";

        }

        else if (numberOfBedrooms > 6){
           document.getElementById("totalPrice").textContent = "329.00";

        }

        else {
            alert("Script error: Undefined number of bedrooms")
        }


        return false;
    }

    else if ((basic.checked == false) && (advanced.checked == true)) { 
        /* Get number of rooms for advanced inspection */

        ids.forEach(logArrayElements);

        if (counter == 0){
            document.getElementById("totalPrice").textContent = "0.00";
        }
        else if (counter == 1){
            document.getElementById("totalPrice").textContent = minimumPrice.toFixed(2);
;
        }
        else {
            var money =  ((counter * priceIncrement) + +minimumPrice) - +priceIncrement;
            document.getElementById("totalPrice").textContent = money.toFixed(2);
        }
            counter=0;

        return false;
    }

    else if ((basic.checked == false) && (advanced.checked == false)) {
        alert("Script error: Neither checkbox is checked");
        return false;
    }

    else if ((basic.checked == true) && (advanced.checked == true)) {
        alert("Script error: Both checkboxes are checked");
        return false;
    }
    else{
        alert("Script error: Unknown error");
        return false;
    }
}


function logArrayElements(element, index, array) {
   // alert("a[" + index + "] = " + element + " - " + value);
    var e = document.getElementById(element);
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    counter = +counter + +strUser;
}

</script>
```

watch-me-hide and watch-me-show are radio buttons that when changed they hide or show another section of the contact form to fill out, and make the inputs required or not.

hideShowInDepth-hide and hideShowInDepth-show are the same, but for another div section.

the price function updates the text in a span to reflect a new price when an input value has changed.

price() gets called onchange of dropdowns and radio buttons.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You need to change `$("input[type="radio"]")` to either `$('input[type="radio"]')` or `$("input[type='radio']")`. There might be other issues, but that looks like one of them to me

Comment: The end tag of `$(document).ready()` is not prper. You have missed `)` braces. Here, `};  `. Please add `)`. i.e. `});` Please try with this once.

Comment: Thanks yes it worked again with fixing those couple of issues. It's strange, when it works, the top bit of my page hides underneath the navigation menu where you cant see it. So then I refresh the page and the page looks better, but then the script stops working!

Comment: will it be more less error to bind the onchange event of the input rather than do it inline, since you're using jquery.

Comment: try this `counter = counter + strUser;` you are adding more `+` in the statement.just replace with in single `+`

Comment: Binding to the on change event for dropdowns, that sounds like a good idea, do you know how to do this for dropdowns?

Comment: The extra + signs just ensure its a number dont they? Otherwise i get things like var x = 11; var y = 22; then x+y=1122